# argparse like lib for PHP?

Tags: php, command-line-interface

Is there a PHP lib that provides similar functionality as the [argparse module of Python](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse)? PHP's [getopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php) certainly doesn't cut it.

What I need:

- required param check and automatic error msg generation.
- correct exit status on error ( > 0 if param parse error).
- error msg's to STDERR.
- help msg generation of all accepted params.
- param type checking is a bonus.

Basically how a *NIX CLI script should behave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Zend_Console_GetOpt](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.console.getopt.rules.html).

Comment: Tnx. Tested it, and is good enough for now. Required param gives only exceptions on type check, not on mere presence.

Answer (score 2):

The most comprehensive library i know of (and the only one i've actually used) is  [Console_CommandLine](http://pear.php.net/package/Console_CommandLine). I have not used argparse so I can't tell you if it is as featured or compare them.

Answer (score 0):

[Docopt](http://docopt.org/), an altogether beautiful command parser, has [a PHP version](https://github.com/docopt/docopt.php).